# React componentWillUpdate getting called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Iam new to React and i came across with this [doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#invoking-external-callbacks). It says that:

> Either way, it is unsafe to use componentWillUpdate for this purpose
>   in async mode, because the external callback might get called multiple
>   times for a single update

How is it possible for the componentWillUpdate to be called multiple times? It doesnt explain it.

Thank you

Comment: Whenever there's a change to the state, the component updates, before it does componentWillUpdate is called. I don't use reactjs and I don't know what version you're running but [here's some more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate).

Comment: Does [this graph](http://www.nikpro.com.au/the-react-component-lifecycle-in-update-stage-shouldcomponentupdate-and-componentdidupdate-part-2/) explain it better? Note that you might have read over the statement that willUpdate is [considered legacy](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#new-lifecycle-getsnapshotbeforeupdate) as well: *together with componentDidUpdate, this new lifecycle should cover all use cases for the legacy componentWillUpdate*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On async mode, your component update/render may be postponed so react can deliver some hi-priority stuff. This means `willUpdate` will be called each time react starts working on your component, but it might not finish the full update, hence calling `willUpdate` every time it starts working on this component but only calls `didUpdate` once, after this process is finished.

Comment: Is there any link or article about this? And by  async mode you mean async operations?

Comment: Async mode is what was previously called `fiber`. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: This link doesnt say anything about  hi-priority

Comment: The async mode is not production ready yet. If your question is regarding a specific piece of code and not just the docs then you should update your answer to be more specific.

Comment: I want a working example with an async mode whereas i can see the drawbacks of using the deprecated methods such as componentWillUpdate in order to understand how async works

Answer (score 2):

Any change that is supposed to trigger a render will first go through a componentWillUpdate lifecycle. The change change can be a parent re-render causing the child to re-render, a change in components props, or a change in state.

However from v16.3.0 this lifecycle method is deprecated and it is encouraged that any sideeffect be handled in componentDidUpdate which will be triggered after render method.